# Opening application automatically by detecting Fitness Equipment cable

Tags: ios

I am developing a LFConnect application for iPhone. When I connect a LF cable to iPhone it should open my application automatically, just like iTunes on the PC.

How can I make the iPhone open an application automatically when a cable is connected?

Comment: As far I know only user 'tap' on icon can open App. I am not sure but iOS could provide this kind of feature.

Comment: LFConnect application having the same feature... so i am trying to implement the same but i didn't fond any solution still now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best place to get answer is https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/. You can register your device in MFI program and using certain 'events' from your device hardware you can launch the application.